# Why am I getting undefined when trying to update state

Tags: reactjs

Basically I am getting coords from a library and updating the state's latitude and longitude to hold them however I get undefined, what may be the reason?

This is my code

```
const [latitude , setLatitiude] = useState(null)
 const [longitude , setLongitude] = useState(null)
    
const {coords, isGeolocationAvailable , isGeolocationEnabled} = useGeolocated({
        positionOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        },
        userDecisionTimeout: 5000
    })


    useEffect (() => {
        setLatitiude(coords.latitude)
        setLongitude(coords.longitude)
    }, [longitude , latitude])
```

Any idea why I am getting that error of undefined, when surely there is data in the coords variable. I know there is data in coords because I console.logged it.

Comment: In the useEffect dep array, you should have [coords] or [coords.longitude, coords.latitude] I think

Comment: Still didn't work

Comment: a sandbox would be helpful to debug this

Comment: where are you getting undefined if you also say 
`I know there is data in coords because i console.logged it`

Comment: When I do my useEffect like - useEffect (() => {
    console.log(coords)
}, [coords])  I do get the data in coords but when I want to set State it stops working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be defining the right dependency on `useEffect`

```
useEffect (() => {
    console.log(coords);
    if (coords) {
       setLatitiude(coords.latitude)
       setLongitude(coords.longitude) 
    }
}, [coords]);
```

Now if you wanted to see the updated latitude and longitude state value then write another `useEffect` with required dependency as setState is asynchronous.

```
useEffect (() => {
   console.log(`latitude: ${latitude}; longitude: ${longitude}`);
}, [latitude, longitude]);
```